# Is it OK to ask OP in a comment to accept an answer?

Tags: discussion

I was looking over my answers and came across [this unanswered question](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/60325/show-log-in-or-sign-up-after-adding-items-to-a-cart-for-an-e-commerce-site/60329#60329) where a user described my answer as "unique and helpful".

I was wondering why the user didn't accept my answer then. It's either they're not satisfied or not aware that such a feature exists. In order to "push" the user into the right direction would it be acceptable to ask the user to accept the answer? This of course also applies to answers that are not mine. E.g. to suggest to take this answer instead of another one, if there's a better answer added after the approval.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, that's OK. If they're a new user they may not know that accepting an answer is possible, so you are just advising them on how to use the site.

[This has been asked before on the main StackExchange Meta site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14994/do-you-feel-dirty-if-you-nudge-new-users-to-accept-your-answer-when-they-indicat), where the below is the (accepted) answer:

> I think that's acceptable. If you were encouraging them to accept an incomplete or unhelpful answer, that would be rep-whoring. Encouraging them to accept a good answer (even your own) is just teaching them the right way to use the system.
>
> Look at it this way, if you saw a comment on someone else's answer that led you to believe it was the right answer, would you leave a comment encouraging the questioner to accept it? You probably would, so you shouldn't feel guilty if you do the same on your own answers.

Comment: Didn't know this is called "rep-whoring" :)

Comment: I AM REFERENCING THIS ON AskUbuntu!