# How to encourage users to accept an answer to a question?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, answers, accepted-answer, engagement

There is an answer to a previous [question](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1662/is-it-ok-to-ask-op-in-a-comment-to-accept-an-answer) that forms a possible answer to this question, but I want to come back to the root cause of the problem of users not choosing or accepting an answer to questions.

Do users also know that they gain some XP for accepting answers?

Are we doing enough to encourage them to do so and thus making each Q&A more complete?

I feel like it is good to try and get to the bottom of this because there is a mutual benefit for the person posting the question and the people who answer them, not to mention the rest of the community that then reads the entry at a future date.

So how can we encourage users to accept an answer to a question? Can/Should a similar system/interaction/behaviour for bounties be implemented?

Comment: Apart from telling them that they *can* accept an answer, I don't see any way to encourage it. The reverse, accepting an answer too soon, is a more serious problem, in my opinion.

Comment: Is there a way for the community to vote on an answer? If not, could that feature be added?

Comment: A similar situation across Stack Exchange is when a user accepts an answer in 2014 that is no longer the best in 2019, but the better answer sits unaccepted unless the user comes back and changes their choice (which is unrealistic because their question has been answered and they never agreed to be the custodian of their question for life).